# How to rebuild this CSS Grid as Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I have build a super simple css grid with the help of Google. The most important part is the space between the elements, but not around the Container itself, only between the elements. I am trying to figure out how to rebuild this css grid as a css flexbox. Could someone help or maybe this isnt possible in css flexbox?

```css
#home-articles-grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
    column-gap: 10px;
    row-gap: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.home-articles-article {
      background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-articles-grid-container">
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
    <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
    <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `flex` solution.

`gap: 20px` - distance between blocks;

`width: calc((100% / 3) - (40px / 3))` - calculation of the block width taking into account the `gap` parameter for the correct distribution in the container.

```css
#home-articles-grid-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap;
    gap: 20px;
    background-color: grey;
}

.home-articles-article {
    background-color: pink;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - (40px / 3));
}
```

```html
<div id="home-articles-grid-container">
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
    <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
    <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>
  <div class="home-articles-article">
      XX
  </div>

</div>
```